# cakephp outputs unexpected fieldnames or field ids

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

What I wanna ask is I dont know where it comes and I am 1200% sure that there are no debug enabled somewhere or outputs something in my application that on the left top of my window always it outputs my primary key field names and sometimes ids after a form post or server side operation. What I use is cakephp >2 framework.

Anybody helps?

Thanks

Comment: You need to debug this like any other problem. e.g. put `die();` in the start of the controller action - see the output? Then it comes from code before that, otherwise from code included/executed after that. Move the `die();` around until you identify where it comes from. Tip: it's not going to be coming out of the core code.

Comment: it does not occur always, thats why my problem is kinda big, what do you mean by your tip?

Answer (score 0):

I  think in your respective controller function you are echoing something when post event
    is fired

```
 ex.
     if ($this->request->is('post'))

      {
         echo $id;
       }

  Please Check your controller function.
```

Comment: no it happens to me since a while and as I wrote in the question I am so sure about it because it is a live system and truly tested until now and why I should output my primary key then

Answer (score 0):

Happening in every controller actions? Why not do a text search using your IDE, look up for suspicious "echo" "debug", "var_dump" or "print_r" in your app folder?

Worst case is something in your view has wrong closing tags that may interfere your page rendering.

Also view source on the offending pages to see whether it's appearing before your DOCTYPE or after. Before means the echoing is before view get rendered, after means it could be during the view rendering.

Hope it helps

Comment: it does not occur always, thats why my problem is kinda big?

Comment: Or could be coming from one of your included plugin/library. For sure cake never do that ;)

Comment: for sure there are some cake functions that output some field names